# Are there digital keyboard that will play music I write on the computer?

Tags: software, digital-piano

I have been trying to compose tracks using the synthesizers provided by software like Sibelius and Finale, but it sounds terrible in terms of the sound quality.

I tried playing some of the stuff on my friend's digital Yamaha keyboard and it sounded just like a real piano when I recorded it.

Is there a model pian or software or both that would allow me to write the music on the computer and then have it played with the digital keyboard?

Comment: You should be able to "play" a digital keyboard from Finale or Sibelius with nothing more complicated than a MIDI cable from your computer to the keyboard. You have to tell the notation program to generate MIDI output instead of using its own synthesizer, of course. But if you mean the software's *interpretation* of the music is "terrible" compared with a *human* performance, changing the playback device won't alter that. The way to get the best results from any sample library is usually to play the samples "live" from a keyboard, not from a notation program.

Comment: Hmmm I think that may answer my question. I will have to get such a cable and keyboard try.

Comment: You certainly don't *have* to buy a digital keyboard to get a pretty good piano sound. Here's a demo comparing three different computer-generated pianos (all "playable" from Sibelius or Finale - I personally use one of the three)  compared with a "real" digital piano. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoEBnCEYmlA

Answer (score 1):

You would use a good plugin (probably a VST) like Addictive Keys to get the MIDI tracks generated by those other programs to sound realistic. A lot of times, the built-in instruments for music programs sound pretty fake.

I don't use Finale myself, but it looks like it supports VST instruments. I'd recommend starting with the Addictive Keys demo so you can hear what it sounds like. Personally, I think it sounds quite realistic, and I use it with a digital piano I have.